# Algorithm that generates all versions of an array with possible weights assigned 0-100

Tags: php, algorithm

I have a following array (php):

```
[
 [id=>1,weight=]
 [id=>2,weight=]
 [id=>3,weight=]
 [id=>4,weight=]
]
```

I need to create all possible versions of this array asigning **0-100** weight to each `item['weight']` with a step of N.

I don't know how this type of problems are called. It is NOT permutation/combination.

Lets say N is 10, I am aiming to get:

```
[
    [
     [id=>1,weight=10]
     [id=>2,weight=10]
     [id=>3,weight=10]
     [id=>4,weight=70]
    ]
    [
     [id=>1,weight=10]
     [id=>2,weight=10]
     [id=>3,weight=20]
     [id=>4,weight=60]
    ]
    [
     [id=>1,weight=10]
     [id=>2,weight=10]
     [id=>3,weight=30]
     [id=>4,weight=50]
    ]
    [
     [id=>1,weight=10]
     [id=>2,weight=10]
     [id=>3,weight=40]
     [id=>4,weight=40]
    ]
    ...all possible combination of weights for id=x.
    [
     [id=>1,weight=70]
     [id=>2,weight=10]
     [id=>3,weight=10]
     [id=>4,weight=10]
    ]
]
```

Sum of 4 `item['weights']` in array on same level is always 100 (or 0.1). And inside parent array I've all possible combinations of weights from 10-100 for id=x.

Comment: So each id should have a subarray of all values from 10-100? Or a complete set o new arrays for each new combination?

Comment: `10 10 10 70` to `70 10 10 10` does not explain range of 0 to 100 with step of 10.! please take a good example.

Comment: @Andreas new arrays for each combination.

Comment: @JayJoshi I will try to give a better example

Comment: @Andreas I rephrased my problem, to the best of my knowledge, is it clearer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theres probably a better way, but heres my attempt:

```
$result=array(); // Empty array for your result
$array=range(1117,7777); // Make an array with every number between 1117 and 7777
foreach ($array as $k=>$v) {  // Loop through numbers
    if ((preg_match('/[890]/',$v) === 0) && (array_sum(str_split($v, 1)) === 10)) { 
        // If number does not contain 8,9 or 0 and sum of all 4 numbers is 10
        // Apply function to multiply each number by 10 and add to result array
        $result[] = array_map("magnitude", str_split($v, 1));
    }
}
function magnitude($val) { // function to multiply by 10 for array map
    return($val * 10);
}
print_r($result);
```

Working demo [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c51f7ac261181bdcb0a8c2cca8d3b5aeca380370)

**EDIT**

Sorry I realised my code explanation isn't totally clear and I condensed it all a bit too much to make it easy to follow.

In your example the first array would contain `(10,10,10,70)`. For the sake of simplicity I divided everything by 10 for the calculations and then just multiplied by 10 once I had a result, so your array of `(10,10,10,70)` becomes `(1,1,1,7)`. Then your final array would be `(70,10,10,10)` which would become `(7,1,1,1)`.

My approach was to first to create an array containing every combination of these four numbers, which I did in two steps.

This line `$array=range(1117,7777);` creates an array like this `(1117, 1118, 1119 ... 7775, 7776, 7777)`  (My number range should really have been 1117 - 7111 instead of 1117-7777).

Applying `str_split($v, 1)` to each value in the loop splits each 4 digit number in the array into another array conatining 4 single digit numbers, so `1117` will become `(1, 1, 1, 7)` etc

As each of your items can't have a weight below 10 or above 70 we use `(preg_match('/[890]/',$v) === 0)` to skip any arrays which have 0,8 or 9 in them anywhere, then `array_sum(str_split($v, 1)) === 10)` adds up the four digits in the array and only returns arrays which total 10 (you wanted ones which total 100, but I divided by 10 earlier).

`array_map` applies a function to each element in an array. In my example the function multiplies each value by 10, to undo the fact I divided by 10 earlier.

When you say is it possible to alter steps, can you give me a couple of examples of other values and the output you want for them?

If you want a totally different approach and using mysql isn't a problem then this also works:

Create a new table with a single row. Insert all the values you need to check

```
INSERT INTO `numbers` (`number`) VALUES
(10),
(20),
(30),
(40),
(50),
(60),
(70);
```

Then your php looks like this

```
$result=array();
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=aaaaa;dbname=bbb', 'ccc', 'dddd');
    foreach($dbh->query('SELECT *
FROM numbers a
CROSS JOIN   // A cross join returns the cartesian product of rows
numbers b    // so every row with every combination of the other rows
CROSS JOIN
numbers c
CROSS JOIN
numbers d
ON
a.number = b.number OR a.number != b.number') as $row) {
        if (($row[0] + $row[1] + $row[2] + $row[3]) === 100) {
            $result[] = $row;
        }
    }
    $dbh = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
print_r($result);
```

Comment: I don’t think you needed to include all 84 items of the result, and certainly not formatted in such a verbose form.

Comment: Not every browser (or the SO app) displays it that way; even listing each of the 84 elements as just a line w/ the 4 numbers would be a big improvement.

Comment: @Scott Hunter Fair point, I've switched it out for a demo link

Comment: Hey, how are you getting these numbers? 1117-7777 and do you think it is possible to alter steps? e.g. change it to 5 6 7 or 10 like you have.

Comment: Updated my answer in response to your follow up

Answer (score 1):

This problem is sometimes described as allocating identical balls into distinct bins. You didn't specify your problem exactly, so I'll take a guess here but the logic will be identical.

I'll assume you're distributing b = N/step balls into 4 bins.

Think of the balls all in a row, and then using 3 bars to separate the balls into 4 bins:
***|**||*****.

If N=10 and you're distributing 100 points, the above example is the same is 30, 20, 0, 50. If zeroes aren't allowed, you can reduce the amount you're distributing by 4*b and assume each bin starts out with N/step in it (so you're distributing the leftover points).

The number of ways to do this is choose(balls + bins - 1, bins - 1).

Comment: Hi, thank you for looking in, I've updated my question. Is it still relevant?